# Elasticsearch : How to get score for each word matched in a match query

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch, lucene

So i have a use case where i need to query on a number of sentences for some particular words, my data set looks like this

```
{
        "_index": "12_index",
        "_type": "skill_strings",
        "_id": "AVKv-kM4axmY3fECZw9T",
        "_source": {
           "str": "SQL Server"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "12_index",
        "_type": "skill_strings",
        "_id": "AVKv-kNfaxmY3fECZw9U",
        "_source": {
           "str": "SQL .net java"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "12_index",
        "_type": "skill_strings",
        "_id": "AVKv-kPDaxmY3fECZw9X",
        "_source": {
           "str": "My SQL java php .net"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "12_index",
        "_type": "skill_strings",
        "_id": "AVKv-kOtaxmY3fECZw9W",
        "_source": {
           "str": "My SQL Server"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "12_index",
        "_type": "skill_strings",
        "_id": "AVKv-kOeaxmY3fECZw9V",
        "_source": {
           "str": "php asp.net Server"
        }
     }
```

And my current query looks like this

```
GET 12_index/skill_strings/_search
{
   "explain": true,
   "query" : { 
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {"match_phrase" : { "str" : "SQL Server" }},
            {"match_phrase" : { "str" : ".net" }}
         ]
      }
   } 
}
```

So the use case is to find the documents with either of the asked skills, and i need to get the individual score of each of the match (i need them for my calculations later). I cant use the overall score of the matched document instead i need the score for each matched word/phrase.

Using explain : true, provides me the explanation of the scoring but im not able to find any way to take this score out and use in java

My java code looks like this

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch(index)
        .setQuery(jsonQuery)
        .setTypes(type)
        .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
        .setFrom(from).setSize(size).setExplain(true)
        .execute()
        .actionGet()

for(SearchHit hit : searchResponse.getHits()){
            def id = hit.getId()
            Map resMap = hit.getSource()
            resMap.eplaination = hit.getExplanation().getDetails()
            resData.add(resMap)
        }
return resData
```

I can see when i do hit.getExplanation().getDetails() i get an object of class org.apache.lucene.search.Explanation but i dont know how to retrieve individual scores out of it. Any help is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`hit.getExplanation().getValue()` will give you the score. As you mentioned `hit.getExplanation().getDetails()` is itself `org.apache.lucene.search.Explanation` array. You can get the `score` of all sub-calculations by calling `getValue()` method.

Comment: Ya i understood that but i need to find the score and the corresponding piece of query as i will be having a lot of other match/range queries in the overall query and i don't need the scores of those. I just need the score for this particular query. Can i do that  ?